# What would grow well under a trampoline?

Tags: sunlight, light, optimal-conditions

We have a trampoline in our garden where the trampoline itself is made from a dark mesh material that lets through light. This means that the lawn underneath grows fine (perhaps a bit slower?). So I was wondering if this would provide good growing conditions for some kind of plant - i.e. one that would need some shade, not too tall. So what *could* you plant under a trampoline?

Comment: rubber plants for extra bounce?   :)

Comment: Ha! I love this image. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd be tempted to try lettuce. I haven't a shady spot in my yard to grow lettuce in the heat of summer, but under the trampoline it would be under shade cloth. Where you thinking of something perennial? I would think you could also try a mix of hostas, wild geraniums, bleeding hearts, and dwarf astilbe. They all like shade and if you picked shorter varieties, they might work...

Answer (score 4):

Nothing useful really. Lamium maculatum varieties, Vinca, but both of these can become invasive, so in a lawn, you wouldn't risk it. Ajuga reptans if it doesn't dry out regularly, but you'd probably have less coloration on the leaves. If the grass is growing and healthy, that's probably the best option.

Answer (score 1):

Google "Shade tolerant ground cover"

Ones that occur to me:

- Bugle weed
- Bishops weed
- Vinca
- Hosta
- violets
- lungwort
- False solomon's seal
- Wolfbane
- Any low fern
- Mosses (requires soil amendment to lower pH)
- Creeping bell flower (invasive in some climates)
- Canada bunchberry
- Bedstraw
- Creeping charly

The above all occur in my woods.  I'm zone 3 with very long winters.